# TwoSlopeNorm in Matplotlib not working as expected

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am trying to create a plot with a diverging colour map which is not symmetric around zero

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146989/6288682) example, the `DivergingNorm` function is used and produces what I want...

[image: Example from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146989/6288682]

I am using a later version of Matplotlib however (3.5.1) and when I use the suggested code in the link above, I get the following image...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.random((10,10))
data = 10 * (data - 0.8)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(data, norm=matplotlib.colors.TwoSlopeNorm(0), cmap=plt.cm.seismic, interpolation='none')
fig.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

[image: TwoSlopeNorm not producing what I want]

... which is clearly not right.

Does anyone know how I can reproduce this behaviour from `DivergingNorm` from older Matplotlib verions? I can't find a solution to this anywhere even though the older behaviour of 'DivergingNorm' is exactly what I want.

I get the same wrong behaviour using this example ---> https://stackoverflow.com/a/69707735/6288682

I should get this...

[image]

... but actually get...

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The norm is still working as expected. What has changed, is the display of the colorbar. I don't know whether this change in behavior is intended by matplotlib's maintainers, or is a side effect of some refactoring. Anyway, previously the ticks would be shown in a linear way and the colors got distorted accordingly. Now, the colors are linear and the ticks are distorted.  (There also seems to be a difference in showing the highest and lowest values, 2 and -8, when they are just outside the data range.) I was expecting the `spacing='uniform'`parameter would make a difference, but it doesn't.

Comment: thanks for your comment @JohanC. it would be interesting to know if the maintainers intended this behaviour.

Comment: You might check the issues at [github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues), and add a new one if it isn't already mentioned.

Comment: thanks @JohanC. i've just asked a question on the matplotlib discourse and will raise a github ticket if nothing comes of that. thanks

---> https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/twoslopenorm-in-matplotlib-not-working-as-expected/23350

Comment: It seems already to be in discussion: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/22197  There `cb.ax.set_yscale('linear')` is suggested as a workarround.

Comment: THANKS!!!!! this has fixed it. i've made a comment on the github thread. imho the documentation should mention this.

Comment: Just to comment on this - this was indeed an explicit design change to make non-linear norms all behave consistently.  In particular, for `LogNorm` the colors are spaced equally, and the scale is what changes.  The changes in MPL 3.6 are meant so that all non linear norms (including `TwoSlopeNorm`) behave the same way.