# How to fix streched colorbar with Matplotlib's TwoSlopeNorm

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function whose image goes from 0 to infinity, for example $f(x,y)=x^2 + y^2$. I would like to use a diverging colormap to highlight the region where the function equals 1 with a flexible colorbar. The colorbar should go from 0 to whatever `vmax`, white ("center") at 1, and the interval between colors should be proportional to numbers.

When plotting it with no constrains, the white region placement depends on the `vmin`-`vmax` range. I would like to have it fixed at 1, `vmin` cannot be less than 0. I partially solve the problem using Matplotloib's `TwtoSlopeNorm` setting the center to 1, whatever the `vmin`-`vmax` range is. But this causes the lower part of the colorbar to take as much space as the upper part, which is not correct. *The colorbar is stretched.* Trying `spacing="proportional"` does nothing. How can I have the colorbar use as much space for the 0-1 range as it does for the other unit intervals, while fixing the white to 1?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
from matplotlib import cm

delta = 0.01
x = np.arange(0, 2.001, delta)
y = np.arange(0.0, 2.001, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = X**2 + Y**2

cmap = cm.seismic

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,5))

ax = fig.add_subplot(131)
plt.pcolormesh(Z, cmap=cmap, vmin=0, vmax=9)
plt.title('White position depends on vmin-vmax range')
plt.colorbar(extend='max')

ax = fig.add_subplot(132)
plt.pcolormesh(Z, cmap=cmap, norm=colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=0, vmax=9, vcenter=1))
plt.title('White position is fixed, but colorbar is streched')
plt.colorbar(extend='max')

ax = fig.add_subplot(133)
plt.pcolormesh(Z, cmap=cmap, norm=colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=0, vmax=9, vcenter=1))
plt.title('spacing="proportional" does not work')
plt.colorbar(extend='max', spacing='proportional')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: See comments in [TwoSlopeNorm in Matplotlib not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74595690/twoslopenorm-in-matplotlib-not-working-as-expected).  This is a [closed github issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/22197). `cb.ax.set_yscale('linear')` is suggested as a workaround.

Comment: Thank you! It does the trick! Confusing that `spacing='proportional'` also sounds logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full answer is [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/24563)

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
from matplotlib import cm

delta = 0.01
x = np.arange(0, 4.001, delta)
y = np.arange(0.0, 4.001, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = X**2 + Y**2

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
m1 = plt.contourf(Z, cmap=cm.seismic, levels=np.arange(0,33,1), norm=colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=0, vmax=32, vcenter=1), extend='max')
plt.colorbar(m1)

ax = fig.add_subplot(122)
m1 = plt.pcolormesh(Z, cmap=cm.seismic, norm=colors.TwoSlopeNorm(vmin=0, vmax=32, vcenter=1))
cb = plt.colorbar(m1, extend='max', spacing='proportional')
cb.ax.set_yscale('linear')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]